# Unable to insert string into Access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, insert

I am using a WPF application to insert a student into my MS Access database.

I wanted to use a parameter with this code:

```
Dim sql As String = _
    "INSERT INTO exams " & _
    "VALUES (@student)"

Dim opdracht As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, connectie)

opdracht.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@student", 5))
```

but this doesn't work.

The only way i get it to work is this one:

```
Dim sql As String = _
    "INSERT INTO exams " & _
    "VALUES (" & student & ")"

' opdracht initialiseren
Dim opdracht As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, connectie)
```

To use this query I use the command, this is the point where I get my error.

```
opdracht.executeNonQuerry()
```

The table layout in MS Access looks like this:

[image: table layout in acces]

And my application inserts the other values corectly but i left them out to keep a minimal example.

Comment: What is the schema of the table exams?

Comment: And, in which way it doesn't work? Do you get an exception with an error message? or simply the record is not inserted?

Comment: Are you running the opdracht.ExecuteNonQuery() after this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a variable named `student` and you want to use its value for the parameter then you need to assign that variable as parameter's value

```
Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO exams VALUES (@student)"
Dim opdracht As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, connectie)
opdracht.Parameters.AddWithValue("@student", student)
opdracht.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Of course, I am assuming this because you say that the string concatenation version is working, and in that example you concatenate the value of a variable named `student` in your command text

Remember that with OleDb the name of your parameters is meaningless because OleDb use the position of the placeholder to pass the parameters' values, not the parameter name

**EDIT** Using INSERT INTO without specifying the column names works only if you add the parameters for all fields. Your database table contains other fields so you need to specify them or use a different syntax for the INSERT INTO

```
Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO exams (Student) VALUES (@student)"
```

But this will fail also because you have the Student field part of your primary key. The fields that belong to a Primary Key cannot be null so you have no choice but add all the values required by the primary key

```
Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO exams (Student, locaal, opleidingsOnderdeel) " & _ 
                    "VALUES (@student, @local, @oplei)"

.. add the parameter's value for student, local and oplei
```

However, I am a bit perplexed that the string concatenation works. What is the value of the variable student? You should get the same error as using the parameterized query with only one parameter.

Comment: This doesn't work, it gives me the same error message

Comment: @Thomas What does the error message **actually say**??

Comment: Answer updated to reflect the new information provided (datatable schema)